# animate google chart on load

Tags: animation, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to get an animation effect for my columns in my Google column chart. According to a similar question posted, the solution was to make the change in the **var option**. I did so, however I still don't see the animation effect. Am I mission something.

Google Chart:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    google.load("visualization", "1.1", { packages: ["bar"] });
                    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                    function drawChart() {

                        var options = {
                            'title': '',
                            'animation': { duration: 1000, easing: 'out', }
                        };

                        var data1 = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                          ['Date', 'Under Review', 'Accepted', 'Rejected', 'In Print', 'Published'],
                           @Html.Raw(rows)]);                          

                        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

                        chart.draw(data1, options);
                    }
                </script>
                <div id="columnchart_material" style="width: 750px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

The Chart does display, but doesn't have that animation effect when I load the page, it simply displays it

Answer (score 2):

Animation is event driven.
To animate "on load", you need to add `startup` to your options...

```
    animation:{
      duration: 1000,
      easing: 'out',
      startup: true
    },
```

Comment: let's just hope it works on Material charts. you may need to convert your options, much like the font reduction...

Comment: nope. looks like the animation effect doesnt work on that specific chart. I even tried converting the options like you said.... chart.draw(data1, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

Answer (score 0):

After much research it seems that Google doesn't yet have the option for Bar charts to animate on load. I found a column chart however that does has an on-load animation option which works for me. Found it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gb758owr/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
                        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                        function drawChart() {                           
                            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                              ['Faculty Name', 'Book', 'Book Chapter', 'Journal Article', 'Conference'],
                               @Html.Raw(rows)]);
                            var options = {
                                animation: {
                                    duration: 1500,
                                    startup: true
                                }
                            };
                            chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                            chart.draw(data1, options);
```